# C++, can I disallow a specific combination of Policies?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Given a class that takes two policy template parameters:

```
template<typename PolicyA, typename PolicyB>
class widget;
```

And the following available policy classes A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3. How can convey that the 1s and 2s are compatible between each other but that A3 is only compatible with B3? That is, only the following instantiations are allowed:

```
widget<A1, B1> w11;    // All valid.
widget<A1, B2> w12;
widget<A2, B1> w21;
widget<A2, B2> w22;
widget<A3, B3> w33;

// No other combination allowed.
```

My failed attempt at using std::enable_if within a specialization was met with a compilation error:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class<A3, enable_if<is_same<B, B3>::value, B3>::type>
{};
```

Comment: The syntax for your specialization seems to be incorrect. (Would have checked a fix, but I have no c++11 compiler nearby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A1; class A2; class A3; class B1; class B2; class B3;

/// Generic type
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class widget
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<T1, A3>::value ^ !std::is_same<T2, B3>::value,
    "Incompatible policy types selected.");
};

/// Some specialization
template <>
class widget<A1, A2>
{
};

widget<A1, B1> w11;
widget<A1, B2> w12;
widget<A2, B1> w21;
widget<A2, B2> w22;
widget<A3, B3> w33;
//widget<A1, B3> w13; // error C2338: Incompatible policy types selected.
//widget<A3, B2> w32; // error C2338: Incompatible policy types selected.
```

Comment: The condition in the static assert might be a bit off... I am not sure but I am inclined to think on `!(T1==A3 ^ T2==B3)`

Comment: Green check for tight one-liner solution through static_assert.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Pure matter of taste. !(A ^ B), !A ^ B, or A ^ !B, whatever... I don't think that any of these have any benefit regarding readability considering the low complexity of this one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already know about [specialized templates](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).

Anyway, an idea would be to define a specialized template for the incompatible types that automatically throws an `IncompatibleException` or something.

So technically the user can define the type, but it would be unusable and completely obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to just make a specialization for each incompatible case, and have it contain something that will trigger a compilation error. Something like this:

```
template <>
class widget<A1, B3> {
  char error__policies_A1_and_B3_are_incompatible[0];
};
```

The char array of length 0 will throw the compiler off, and the "message" will appear somewhere in the compilation error.

Comment: Identifiers containing adjacent underscores are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Besides the issue with the double underscore, this is not maintainable as the number of specializations required grows by O(N*M), where N is the number of the options for the first argument and M is the number of options for the second argument.